# ScrollView not accepting multiple child

Tags: android

Hello I need to set scroll view in following code,and set after first relative layout but it gives me :
main.xml: IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

that means i cant use scrollview  in multiple layout child.So how can i use scroll view inside first relative layout and cover with all inner relative layout.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/page1_11"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_01" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shanesh COLORS App"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#49515F"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_01" android:id="@+id/login_rellay_02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/page1_4"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/page1_2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/page1_3"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_03" android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_5"
            android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_5" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <!-- <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/imgv_page1_5" 
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_6" 
            android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_6" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" /> -->
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_03" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SIGN IN "
                android:textSize="13dp" android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="with your "
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shanesh Colors"
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_2"
                android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text=" App Account "
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_3"
                android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_04" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_width="306dp" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_6"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />



        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_04" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="User Name:"
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textSize="11dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#49515F" />

            <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" />



        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_05" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_04">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" Password:"
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textSize="11dp" 
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#49515F" />

            <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" />



        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_06" 
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_05" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textColor="#000000"
                      android:text="No Account?"

                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textSize="11dp" 
                      android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_9" 

                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:text="Sign Up" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/login_txvx_signup_account" 
          android:textColor="#8891A2" 
          android:textStyle="bold" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_9"
          android:textSize="11dp" 
         /></RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_07" 

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_06" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_txvx_signup_account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#49515F" 
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text=" Remember User Name and Password?" 
          />

          </RelativeLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_08" 

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_04" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

          <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/page1_8"
                     />
          </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the outer most element the scrollview, which will give only one child your top-level relativelayout.